# How to store multiple for loops with nested lists?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am trying to store a nested for loop outcome but I find it hard to do so. This is what I have:

```
library("pageviews")

lang = c("it.wikipedia", "de.wikipedia", "fr.wikipedia", "es.wikipedia")
bm = c("ECB","Christine Lagarde")

x = list(list()) # store results

for (i in 1:length(lang)) {
  for (j in 1:length(bm)) {

  x[[i]][[j]] = article_pageviews(project = lang[i], article = bm[j], platform = "all", user_type = "user", start = "2015100100", end = today(), reformat = TRUE, granularity = "daily") 

  }
}

x = do.call(rbind, x) # from list to df
```

What I would like to do is to run the code for each `lang` and `article` and store it accordingly. So I would have a list with `it.wikipedia` for ECB, `it.wikipedia` for Lagarde, etc...

Can anyone help me do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need a nested loop. One way to do that using `map_df` from `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)
map_df(lang, function(x) map_df(bm, function(y) 
       article_pageviews(project = x, article = y, platform = "all", user_type = "user", 
       start = "2015100100", end = today(), reformat = TRUE, granularity = "daily"))) -> result
```

Comment: I have been a fan of yours and I request your support on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406140/11096022 when you have few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

So, your approach is correct. But you forgot some things; you want to store for each language, two articles.

Therefore you need 4 lists, such that,

```
x <- list(
    list(),
    list(),
    list(),
    list()
    )
```

And as your lists are nested, you need to undo this by using `purrr::flatten()`, such that,

```
x <- do.call(rbind, purrr::flatten(x)) # from list to df
```

After your `for-loop`

Comment: On an honest sidenote, I would use @Ronak's solution, as, at some point, the amount of lists just becomes a real pain to work with.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your comments! I learned quite a bit from all of you!

Comment: Then it has been a good day! :-) Good luck with whatever you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck at creating nested `list` via nested `for` loops, perhaps the code example below could help

```
a <- letters[1:5]
b <- LETTERS[1:5]

x <- c()
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  u <- c()
  for (j in seq_along(b)) {
    u <- c(u, list(paste0(a[i], "-", b[j])))
  }
  x <- c(x, list(u))
}
```

where `u` and `x` are used to gather lists at different layers, such that

```
> x
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a-A"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "a-B"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "a-C"

[[1]][[4]]
[1] "a-D"

[[1]][[5]]
[1] "a-E"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "b-A"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b-B"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "b-C"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "b-D"

[[2]][[5]]
[1] "b-E"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "c-A"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "c-B"

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "c-C"

[[3]][[4]]
[1] "c-D"

[[3]][[5]]
[1] "c-E"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "d-A"

[[4]][[2]]
[1] "d-B"

[[4]][[3]]
[1] "d-C"

[[4]][[4]]
[1] "d-D"

[[4]][[5]]
[1] "d-E"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "e-A"

[[5]][[2]]
[1] "e-B"

[[5]][[3]]
[1] "e-C"

[[5]][[4]]
[1] "e-D"

[[5]][[5]]
[1] "e-E"
```